# knockout grid with dynamic observables and html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to implement knockout grid with dynamic observables and html template.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukJuN/26/) is here.

I have two templates created, read and write. When one clicks on cell, it should get converted into editable mode. But its applying editing template to complete column. 
can anyone please help on this?

```js
var DynamicObservable = function(data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        this[key] = ko.observable(data[key]);
    }
    
    selectedCell = ko.observable();
    
    templateToUse = function(item) {
        return item === this.selectedCell() ? 'write' : 'read';
    };
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(i) {
        return new DynamicObservable(i);
    }));
    self.columns = ko.observableArray();
    for (var key in data[0]) {
        self.columns.push(key);
    }
    
    self.cellClick = function(){
        debugger;
        
    };
}

var init = [
    { name: "John", age: 23, weight: 145 },
    { name: "Tim", age: 25, weight: 143 },
    { name: "Alex", age: 22, weight: 142 }
];

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(init));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<b>Click on cell to edit</b>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item'}">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
            <td data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse }, event:{click:selectedCell}"> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>

<script id="read" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="text: item[$data]"></div>    
</script>

<script id="write" type="text/html">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: item[$data]"/>  
</script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: On click of any cell, only that single cell should get editable. Just like cellEdit mode in most of jquery grid plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this could be simplified, but it is working. There was previously no check in the "templateToUse" function for what row was clicked on.

Updated [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ukJuN/27/)

```js
var DynamicObservable = function(data, rowIndex, parentSelectedRowIndex,parentSelectedColumnName) {
    self = this
    for (var key in data) {
        self[key] = ko.observable(data[key]);
    }
    
    self.selectCell = function(columnName) {
        parentSelectedRowIndex(rowIndex)
        parentSelectedColumnName(columnName)
    }
    
    self.templateToUse = function(columnName) {
        return rowIndex == parentSelectedRowIndex() && columnName == parentSelectedColumnName () 
                        ? 'write' : 'read';
    };
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.parentSelectedRowIndex = ko.observable(null);
    self.parentSelectedColumnName = ko.observable(null);
    
    self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(i) {
        var myIndex = data.indexOf(i);
        return new DynamicObservable(i, myIndex, self.parentSelectedRowIndex, self.parentSelectedColumnName);
    }));
    self.columns = ko.observableArray();
    for (var key in data[0]) {
        self.columns.push(key);
    }
    
    self.cellClick = function(){
        debugger;
        
    };
}

var init = [
    { name: "John", age: 23, weight: 145 },
    { name: "Tim", age: 25, weight: 143 },
    { name: "Alex", age: 22, weight: 142 }
];

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(init));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<b>Click on cell to edit</b>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item'}">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
            <td data-bind="template: { name: item.templateToUse }, event:{click:item.selectCell}"> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>

<script id="read" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="text: item[$data]"></div>    
</script>

<script id="write" type="text/html">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: item[$data]"/>  
</script>
```

It's a little messy passing the "parentSelected" observables around and if I think of a better way to do it, I'll post an update.

Comment: Yes there was no check of selected row and that's the only thing where I was struggling. 
thanks for all your help